# transaction reached the deadline set due to leeway on account CPU limits

Tags: transactions, resources

[image: transaction reached the deadline set due to leeway on account CPU limits]

I get this error while delegating resources from one account to other account. Is this because i have low available cpu and available net in my account? If so how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

That means payer "safarilion23" has limited CPU usage quota. You should expand "safarilion23"'s CPU quota first.

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference between the following two errors - "tx_cpu_usage_exceeded" and "deadline_exception"